# How to force load chunks using commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a Minecraft Bedrock Realm and I use command blocks all the time for magic weapons and other things. My only issue is they don't stay loaded, therefore the command blocks are not active. I was wondering if there's a command that reliably loads the chunks. I have heard of some command sequence that does it.

I am on Minecraft Bedrock version 1.19.20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tickingarea#Syntax), it's

```
/tickingarea add <from: x y z> <to: x y z> [name: string] [preload: Boolean]
```

to add a ticking area, and

```
/tickingarea remove <name: string>
```

to delete a ticking area.