# How do i keep command blocks on without having a player in the chunk?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Not sure if the chunk isnt loaded or what but i cant figure out how to keep a command block running. I've been having an idea to make a jetpack but the block wolnt stay loaded so i cant use it without being in the chunk. Tried putting a named dog in the chunk but it didnt keep the chunk loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force load chunks using commands?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/398668/how-to-force-load-chunks-using-commands)

Comment: Ok thx man. Thats super helpful.